# Are my Pop or Push method in my Stack class written incorrectly?

Tags: java, stack

When I try to test this out; for example, If I push 4 elements, and then I create a for loop:

```
for( int i=0; i<=stack.size(); i++){
System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

It doesn't output the last element. Is it a problem with my pop method?

```
 public void push(E element){
    top= new Node<E>(element,top);
    size++;

}

public E pop(){
    E popped;
    if(this.isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    popped=top.data;
    this.setTop(top.next);
    size--;
    return popped;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to show the entire class. Using `<=` rather than `<` ought to throw an exception.

Comment: How many elements do you expect to be printed? BTW you are iterating `stack.size()+1` times...

Comment: please menttion code more clearly

Comment: I've noticed you only run push when called. Are you sure that's not it?

Comment: If i push 4 elements, and use < instead of <= in the for loop, it prints only 2 elements. When i use <= it prints 3.

Comment: Then this is a n+1 situation. Happens pretty much. It can solve it.

Comment: Then my next questions are: do you see an `EmptyStackException` and what is the code for the constructor `Node<E>(element,top)`?

Comment: @pinkieswirl got it, you're both incrementing `i` **and** decrementing `size` at the same time, so your loop terminates faster you think it will.

Comment: Yes I see now that my initial comment was rather dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate through your stack with the size.

Just see what happens in your for loop:

1. i = 0; size = 4; i <= size == true
2. i = 1; size = 3; i <= size == true
3. i = 2; size = 2; i <= size == true
4. i = 3; size = 1; i <= size == false

So you don't pop the last element.

But rather than using a for loop with size as limit you should implement a `hasNext()` method, that returns true, if the stack has a next element:

```
while(stack.hasNext())
{
    Element e = stack.pop();
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Or `pop()` returns null if no more elements are on the stack and you loop through it like this:

```
Element e;
while((e = stack.pop()) != null)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I would, as it is though a transient thought, you should do .size()+1;

Comment: This would be even more wrong on so many levels that I can't write them in comment form. Furthermore it would not solve the problem at all, since it would be 0,5 (true) -> 1,4 (true) -> 2,3 (true) -> 3,2 (false, loop stops). So you still would pop only 3 elements. The problem here is, that the size of the stack is reduced, while you loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.pop()` the size of your variable get's 1 less so it wwould be better if you leave out the increment at the end of your loop turn:

```
for( int i=0; i<=stack.size(); ){
  System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```